# Use microphone from remote computer

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone

The microphone from my Thinkpad T470p is broken and this model does not appear to support a 3,5mm external microphone. However, I do have a computer in the same network which does have 3,5mm jack.

Is it possible to somehow pipe the 3,5mm microphone through to my laptop, so I can use it as an audio device for Skype etc? Both devices run Windows 10.

Comment: A quick peek at Lenovo's site shows that model has a 3.5mm combo jack. You can get a splitter that breaks that port out into a separate microphone and headphone jack.

Comment: you audio card is a usb device ?

Comment: Unfortunately the 3,5mm jack is integrated onto the motherboard.

Comment: It's easily possible with Pulseaudio on Linux, BTW. No matter if the audio card is a USB device, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Only if your audio-card is USB device

A solution that work on linux and on Windows is to share a USB device thru the localnetwork .

UsbIp can export a local usb device to a remote local computer .

https://github.com/cezanne/usbip-win

Alternative use a audio server ( https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/About/ )